# HTML5 Presentation - Track Movement on Other Devices

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an HTML based presentation which will be used on a Windows-based Kiosk (Touch Screen) and also the audience will have iPads with the same presentation.

Can anyone suggest a way that I can, when the presenter taps on a nav element, have the iPads mirror what is happening on the kiosk screen?

I thought there may be a javascript plugin to allow me to do this?

Comment: JavaScript runs in one browser tab, it cannot do anything outside the tab it's running in (for security reasons) let alone on another device entirely. Get the users to tap along with you. It'll force them to be more engaged in what you're saying, if they genuinely want to follow your presentation and not just daydream until coffee time.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for that, is there no way to set up a local server and do something like this? I have seen something similar in CodeKit for the mac but can't work out how to replicate it

Comment: I'm not familiar with CodeKit, sorry. AFAIK you'd have to use something like WebSockets I guess to communicate with each device. That would have to be built into the presentation website. Either that or you don't literally load the presentation on the iPads, instead they connect to some kind of video conference / remote desktop thing where they're simply viewing your screen rather than having their own instance of the website running. But I still recommend to forget about technical solutions and use this as an opportunity to make your presentation more interactive :-)

Comment: @ADyson I agree however the presentation team have requested this functionality, I have found https://browsersync.io which seems to do what I need so I will have a play with that. Thanks for your feedback and responses.

Answer (score 0):

After some Googling and a tip from another user, https://browsersync.io seems to solve the issue.